# Python: Printing variables and strings in same line

Tags: python, string, variables, printing

I am currently trying to make a program that will print if variable `a` is divisible by variable `b`. I keep running into errors when trying to print the values a and b.

My code:

```
a, b = eval(input('Input a list of 2 numbers: '))
a = str(a)
b = str(b)
if (a % b == 0):
    print ( a + 'is divisible by' + b)
else:
    print( a + 'is not divisible by' + b)
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Noah/Documents/Python/Assignment 4 Question 7.py", line 4,    in 
>       if (a % b == 0):
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: I modified the code according to your answers, and am now getting an error on line 5.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are casting `a` and `b` to `strings`. You're most likely putting them in as `int`, which they should be. If for some reason you aren't, then the casts should be `a = int(a)`, etc.

Also `eval` is to be avoided, you could change this to:

```
a = input('insert a number')
b = input('insert another number')
```

Or if you aboslutely have to enter them at once, you could do

```
a, b = input('Insert two numbers separated by commas').split(',')
```

Just make sure to not have spaces between them, or, to be safe, when casting you can do

```
a = int(a.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this.

```
a, b = eval(input('Input a list of 2 numbers: '))
```

don't use eval() for a few more years.  Even then use with extreme caution.

```
a = str(a)
b = str(b)
```

str() turns whatever is in there into a string which makes...

```
if (a % b == 0):  #this is where your error is
```

impossible to do because the "%" modulo operator is expecting numbers on either side.
Since these are supposed to be numbers try wrapping a and b in int() or float() statements

```
a = input('Input the first number: ')
b = input('Input the second number: ')
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if (a % b == 0):
    print( a + 'is divisible by' + b)
else:
    print( a + 'is not divisible by' + b)
```